# Should we have a canonical question for retrieving data from devices with broken screens?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

Lately I have noticed a TON of these questions.  It seems to me that the process is basically the same for any device —use ADB to pull files, or install a custom recovery and do a Nandroid backup, etc.  Would it be better just to have a single question that we can collapse the solutions into?

There are a couple other question types that could benefit from this too, notably "I forgot my device password, halp" which seems to have questions closed as dupes somewhat irregularly and to different questions.  I would appreciate suggestions as to which post we should turn into the canonical one (if we do so at all), and any other questions for other topics that should have the same treatment.

Comment: We really should. I support this completely.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with this yes, it is a regular issue for people. I will look into previous posts. OT: I'd love one that just says "Because it's CyangenMod" that alone would answer about 1,000 questions!

Comment: Yes. And separate sections for USB debugging enabled, disabled, referring to all major ROMs available.

Comment: @MatthewRead Great idea. I support this too.

Answer (score 2):

To some extent this can be generalised but since most of the solutions are low level, it would be wise to have a generic question per brand or similar. For instance, Samsung devices use ODIN/Download mode while most of the others use fastboot. Both can be used to access the device while either of them uses a different approach.

Comment: Why shouldn't all methods be in one spot?

Comment: There are many Chinese devices that neither supports ODIN nor fastboot flashing (I have two such devices). Having a per brand question/answer would result in too much scattering since users can't recall every question and they won't be able to direct a new user to the existing solution.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to have a "metaquestion" that would describe the generic way with all the devices specific steps being linked to their respective questions. And, of course, we'd have to accept the fact that we can't support every single device on the market, especially those with low penetration. As for the non-fastboot Chinese devices, what approach is there to flash them, if any?

Answer (score -8):

I think its not possible to know from every android device in the world either if they use fastboot or odin or even which sequence of buttons they need to use...i think its just better a generic topic that should point people to xda-developers forum where they can find their right info for their devices plus more generic information about the process

Comment: The question is not primarily about getting into download mode. We can't certainly point to other resources about that, but it's hardly a reason to abandon the guide entirely.

Comment: I was not saying to abandon the guide just saying to it be generic about the processes since is not possible to give detailed instructions to ALL android devices we can tell them what is ADB Odin fastboo/download mode tell them what is nandroid backup etc but nothing more than that

Comment: And i was going to post this as a comment now i see i posted as answer lol..but anyway i candidate to help to build an answer